# Breaking out of a for loop inside of python string join() Method

Tags: python, string, for-loop, join, break

My code is :

```
maxlimit = 5
mystring = ' \r\n '.join([('' if (idx >= maxlimit) else str(name))
                         for idx,name in enumerate(queryset)])
```

How can I to break out of the for loop inside of `join()` method if `idx >= maxlimit` ?

Comment: You can just slice (or [islice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)) the list: `... for idx,name in list(enumerate(queryset))[:maxlimit]`

Comment: @Rawing Just to nitpick OP will need `[:maxlimit + 1]`. Also the whole `if` becomes unnecessary: `' \r\n '.join(str(name) for name in queryset[:maxlimit + 1])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you should use the `if` condition in the list comprehension instead:

```
mystring = ' \r\n '.join([str(name) for idx, name in enumerate(queryset) 
                          if idx < maxlimit])
```

This generates a list of 5 items only.

But then it is easier to just limit the number of items to iterate with [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice'); or if the queryset (which I do not know what it supports), supports slicing, then just slice it with `[:maxlimit]`:

```
from itertools import islice
' \r\n '.join([str(name) for name in islice(queryset, maxlimit)])
```

---

Though for a simple application of one function to each element, I often use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) as it requires less typing:

```
' \r\n '.join(map(str, islice(queryset, maxlimit)))
```